# xslt getting the value of node in a loop for a specified range

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, if-statement, foreach

I have a xml drafted as follows:

```
  <node index="1">value1</node>
  <node index="2">value2</node>
  <node index="3">value3</node>
  <node index="4">value4</node>
  ...
```

I would like to specify a range, say index from 2~6, and output these values each within a  tag.

Currently I am doing something like:

```
  <xsl:variable name="location" select="/node" />

  <xsl:for-each select="($location[position() &gt;= 2 and position() &lt;= 6])">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$location[.]" /> </td>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work..any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using: v1 or V2?

Comment: I'm using v1 but if you don't mind teaching me both that would be great!

Comment: Your XSLT code doesn't make much sense (why are you looking at position() if you want  to limit by index?), but before this: your XML has no root element, thus cannot be processed at all.

Comment: `/node` is an absolute path that looks for elements named `node` at the _root_ level of the XML.  Since an XML document can only have one root-level element this is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys! I just edited my post. In my original code I did not just use "/node" so please just assume "$node" in the edited post represents a valid Xpath

Comment: Your edit makes no sense whatsoever. You cannot have multiple multiple variables with the same name. I suggest you post a minimal but **complete** example of your XML and XSLT - including the variables definitions.

Comment: just edited again. let me know if it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xsl:for-each` sets the context node – the base for relative XPath expressions – on each iteration. Therefore if the `for-each` is matching the correct nodes (which looks OKish: there can only be a single root node in an XML document, so including a position check won't work unless it is 1: I assume the Q is simplified from the real code) then you should be able to use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="(/node[position() &gt;= 2 and position() &lt;= 6])">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="." /> </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This cannot work: if `/node` is a valid XPath, then there can be only one.

Comment: @michael.hor257k true – I can only assume the real path in the `for-each` is rather longer (hence my caveat). But the real point here is setting the context node.